# Understanding Nodes Approach to CAs

Tags: node.js, ssl, smtp, nodemailer

This question has been asked in different forms before but what I have understood seems too crazy to be right!

I am using nodemailer smtp-transport for connection to a coporate smtp server which requires TLS. As part of this I can specify the tls options that ultimately ends up in the node TLS object.

I have been provided with their internal, self-signed CA for the server which works correctly when testing outside of node by installing to the system and using openssl to test.

So in node I run:

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
  host:'host',
  port:25,
  auth: {
    user: 'user',
    pass: 'pass'
  },
  debug: true,
  requireTLS: true,
  tls: {
    ca: [fs.readFile(caPath)]
  }
}));
```

According to the node help the ca entry is:

> ca: An array of strings or Buffers of trusted certificates in PEM format. If this is omitted several well known "root" CAs will be used, like VeriSign. These are used to authorize connections.

However I still get the node error 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE'. Surely the CA should be trusted, despite being self signed as I have passed to to the CA entry?

Comment: I think you should be using `fs.readFileSync` instead of `fs.readFile`

Comment: That is the only problem, works fine with the change, thanks!